# Play store says Samsung Note 8 is not compatible with an app i developed

Tags: android, eclipse, screen-size, samsung-galaxy, screen-density

Play store says Samsung Note 8 is not compatible with an app i developed for phones only by using the screen size and density, how can i add on the note 8 specs for play store to detect, i have tried searching on google but the note 8 seems to new for anyone to have had the issue yet.

Comment: Samsung note 8 isn't compatible because of your `targetSdkVersion` of your app.
Change your `targetSdkVersion`.

Comment: Did your app support other devices that have OS version of Samsung Note 8?

Comment: Please specify `targetSdkVersion` and what is your Samsung Note 8 os ?

Comment: app was developed couple years back so definitely not targeting sdk 26... tanx guys will try it out.

Comment: Did you solve the issue?

Comment: ok so i have a xiaomi mi 6 which has android 8.0 (sdk 26) but playstore says app is compatible with it so it cant be the sdk thats a problem.